# What do you call an email address connected to a function rather than a person?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

As the heading suggests, I'm wondering what you call an email address that is linked to a certain function rather than to a specific person. For instance, at my department at uni, there are three different people sharing the responsibilities of the director of studies, and so, there is a mail for this function (director of studies), that all three of them have access to. In my own language we call this a "function mail", but I haven't found very convincing support for this in English, so I'm wondering if it's called something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who has maintained these kinds of email addresses in a helpdesk job, we called these ***generic** email addresses*

Comment: Yes. Shared inbox, or generic inbox.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably call this a "shared address". But I don't believe there is any term in English describing this sort of thing.

Note that there are plenty of function-based addresses that can still be routed to just one person, webmaster@domain or postmaster@domain for example. While large companies may have more than one person handle these addresses smaller ones are very likely to have just one.

Comment: Very good point! The feature I'm after is its being generic/function-based rather than shared :)

Answer (score -1):

I would call this an ***institutional** email address*.

Comment: not sure that is quite right.  An institutional email address is one provided by your institution. So if I work at the bbc, my institution email address might be james.k@bbc.com Unlike my private email address that is provided by my isp or gmail/hotmail etc.  An institutional email address doesn't have to be tied to a role or function.